# Possible to write flash content in C#?

Tags: c#, flash

I've been googling this for a bit but haven't come across anything definitive. Is it possible (by which I also mean practical) to compile Flash swf apps using C#?

Comment: Yeah basically, write C# code and compile it to flash. Sort of like a MonoTouch for Flash, a way to hook in C# code to make use of Flash APIs.

Comment: You realize you'd be giving up the .NET framework?

Comment: Why would I be giving up the .net framework?

Comment: Because there is no implementation of .NET on the Flash platform (and there could not be anything more than a partial one anyway, because of Flash's security limitations). The .NET and Flash frameworks have very different limitations and purposes -- it would be much saner to write C# targeting the Flash API than to implement a subset of .NET using the Flash API and code against that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually [SWF is open format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf.html), so yes you can but it's not easy.

I've done this on a few projects - mainly because at the time Flash 5 was quite limiting (you couldn't dynamically load in an image).

These days there isn't much need to output SWF in code and the automation tools also make other solutions more appealing. It is certainly possible, but to have to write it byte-by-byte. Although these days there are probably a few C# libraries kicking around for it.

Practical? No.

Answer (score 2):

I have no definitive reference to point to but the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the Flash Player External API to create Flash documents in C#. I don't know what the capabilities are exactly, but it's worth taking a look:

Here's an article that explains how to use the API:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/flashexternalapi.aspx

And here's a component that leverages the API:
http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.flash-for-.net/default.aspx